# How to pass in a Range parameter for VLookup function?

Tags: function, excel, range, vlookup, vba

I have the two functions below in VBA. The `abb00` works fine but the `abb11` does not.

My question is how to pass in a `Range` variable as a parameter for `VLookup` function?

```
Function abb00() 'demo func
    abb00 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("a", _ 
        Worksheets("SheetCache").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
End Function

Function abb11() 'demo func
    rangeVar = Worksheets("SheetCache").Range("A:B")
    abb11 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("a", rangeVar, 2, False)
End Function
```

Comment: I just tested both of these functions and they return the exact same result. What exactly do you mean by "`abb11` does not work"?

Comment: I get a `runtime error 13 type mismatch` error for the second function as the variant array exceeds 65536 records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in two ways

**Fixing your Function**
Your current Function is not setting a range variable. It will work like this

```
Function abb11()
    Dim rangeVar as Range
    Set rangeVar = Worksheets("SheetCache").Range("A:B")
    abb11 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("a", rangeVar, 2, False)
End Function
```

**Passing a Range to  your Function**
Alternatively you can pass a range to the Function like this

```
Sub GetRange()
    Dim rangeVar As Range
    Set rangeVar = Worksheets("SheetCache").Range("A:B")
    MsgBox abb2(rangeVar)
End Sub
Function abb2(ByVal rangeVar)
       abb2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("a", rangeVar, 2, False)
End Function
```

Comment: "Your current Function is not setting a range variable." True, but ironically this doesn't impact its output. `rangeVar = ...` reads the entire range `A:B` into a Variant array, and applies `VLookup` to that array, which as far as I call tell, returns the exact same results as applying `VLookup` to the range itself.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett On my testing the Variant died as it was too big for `VLOOKUP` to work on. Did you try xl03 (65536 rows are ok)?

Comment: Aha, that's it. I'm on 2003. Good point. +1  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

To pass a range, you first need to get a reference to a range.

You currently have this:

```
rangeVar = Worksheets("SheetCache").Range("A:B")
```

This doesn't get a range; it reads the entire range `A:B` into a Variant array. If you want to get a range reference, you need to use the `Set` keyword.

```
Set rangeVar = Worksheets("SheetCache").Range("A:B")
```

Ironically this doesn't impact the output of your `abb11` function (*EDIT: in Excel 2003*), because `VLookup` can be applied to a Variant array as well as to a Range. However, reading two whole columns into an array is rather inefficient, so I would stick to getting a range reference (`Set rangeVar = ...`). **EDIT** In Excel 2007/2010, reading two entire columns into a Variant array will probably cause your function to die, because there are a million rows to load as opposed to 65536 in Excel 2003, which is what I was testing.